# Will activiti give call back if due date is completed

Tags: activiti

I have used activiti as state machine and implemented  task  listener interface.. Will I get a call back if particular  task due date is completed I have to update my own tables.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you add a boundary timer event in your process that fires at the due date. As far as Activiti is concerned, due date is simply another piece of task and process instance metadata. You can use it, but you need to model alerts.

Comment: No I cannot  add a boundary timer event,I have some limitations. Any other way to do it

Comment: You cannot add a boundary event timer manually because it screws up your diagram, or for technical reasons?
I would suggest you look into parse handlers, they provide a means to automatically add this capability to activities when you deploy the process.

Comment: Hi Greg ,If i add a boundary timer while transformation I need to specify out going sequence flow also.Is it proper way of doing it

Comment: It will all get pretty complex because you will need to add a boundary timer, flow and notifier service task then flow somewhere else. Likely it will get too complex and difficult to maintain